# Android eclipse questions - snapshots and @category/#pragma mark

Tags: android, xcode, eclipse, version-control

I am used to xCode and read everywhere that Eclipse is supposed to be better...
So far I have found quite some advantages, however now I have two features that I would like in Eclipse and can't find them or they don't work as expected

1. Snapshots of the project - with the click of a button the current configuration of the project is saved and can easily be restored including all settings and source code changes
2. Grouping with @category works differently than I have found it explained. when I do

I get in the outline view just sth like:

```
   initScreen() : void - [mycat]
```

if I write:

```
  /**
   * @category mycat
   */
public void initScreen() { 

    }
```

I would expect something like a grouping with "mycat" as the groups headline, like

```
[mycat]
   initScreen() : void
   anyOther() : void
   ...
```

In general, what is the best, most widely method + easy to use! to do source code management with Eclipse?

Many thanks